# Invalid lunch combo: lunch sdk_phone_x86

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source

I've been trying to build ASOP and emulate it on my Ubuntu machine [the guide by Android documentation](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/download/downloading) to download the repo. The commands are:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
repo sync -c -j31
source build/env_setup.sh
```

After the repo has been cloned, I cannot find the lunch combo `sdk_phone_x86_64` as I am supposed to according to [this guide to build for emulator](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/avd). Instead, I get other combos that I cannot understand:

```
Lunch menu .. Here are the common combinations:
     1. aosp_arm-trunk_staging-eng
     2. aosp_arm64-trunk_staging-eng
     3. aosp_barbet-trunk_staging-userdebug
     4. aosp_bluejay-trunk_staging-userdebug
     5. aosp_bluejay_car-trunk_staging-userdebug
     6. aosp_bramble-trunk_staging-userdebug
     7. aosp_bramble_car-trunk_staging-userdebug
     8. aosp_cf_arm64_auto-trunk_staging-userdebug
     9. aosp_cf_arm64_phone-trunk_staging-userdebug
     10. aosp_cf_riscv64_phone-trunk_staging-userdebug
     11. aosp_cf_x86_64_auto-trunk_staging-userdebug
     12. aosp_cf_x86_64_auto_mdnd-trunk_staging-userdebug
     13. aosp_cf_x86_64_foldable-trunk_staging-userdebug
     14. aosp_cf_x86_64_only_phone_hsum-trunk_staging-userdebug
     15. aosp_cf_x86_64_pc-trunk_staging-userdebug
     16. aosp_cf_x86_64_phone-trunk_staging-userdebug
     17. aosp_cf_x86_64_tv-trunk_staging-userdebug
     18. aosp_cf_x86_phone-trunk_staging-userdebug
     19. aosp_cf_x86_tv-trunk_staging-userdebug
     20. aosp_cheetah-trunk_staging-userdebug
     21. aosp_cheetah_car-trunk_staging-userdebug
     22. aosp_cheetah_hwasan-trunk_staging-userdebug
     23. aosp_cloudripper-trunk_staging-userdebug
     24. aosp_coral-trunk_staging-userdebug
     25. aosp_coral_car-trunk_staging-userdebug
     26. aosp_felix-trunk_staging-userdebug
     27. aosp_flame-trunk_staging-userdebug
     28. aosp_flame_car-trunk_staging-userdebug
     29. aosp_lynx-trunk_staging-userdebug
     30. aosp_oriole-trunk_staging-userdebug
     31. aosp_oriole_car-trunk_staging-userdebug
     32. aosp_panther-trunk_staging-userdebug
     33. aosp_panther_car-trunk_staging-userdebug
     34. aosp_panther_hwasan-trunk_staging-userdebug
     35. aosp_raven-trunk_staging-userdebug
     36. aosp_raven_car-trunk_staging-userdebug
     37. aosp_ravenclaw-trunk_staging-userdebug
     38. aosp_redfin-trunk_staging-userdebug
     39. aosp_redfin_car-trunk_staging-userdebug
     40. aosp_redfin_vf-trunk_staging-userdebug
     41. aosp_slider-trunk_staging-userdebug
     42. aosp_sunfish-trunk_staging-userdebug
     43. aosp_sunfish_car-trunk_staging-userdebug
     44. aosp_tangorpro-trunk_staging-userdebug
     45. aosp_tangorpro_car-trunk_staging-userdebug
     46. aosp_trout_arm64-trunk_staging-userdebug
     47. aosp_trout_x86_64-trunk_staging-userdebug
     48. aosp_whitefin-trunk_staging-userdebug
     49. aosp_x86-trunk_staging-eng
     50. aosp_x86_64-trunk_staging-eng
     51. arm_krait-trunk_staging-eng
     52. arm_v7_v8-trunk_staging-eng
     53. armv8-trunk_staging-eng
     54. armv8_cortex_a55-trunk_staging-eng
     55. armv8_kryo385-trunk_staging-eng
     56. car_ui_portrait-trunk_staging-userdebug
     57. car_x86_64-trunk_staging-userdebug
     58. db845c-trunk_staging-userdebug
     59. gsi_car_arm64-trunk_staging-userdebug
     60. gsi_car_x86_64-trunk_staging-userdebug
     61. hikey-trunk_staging-userdebug
     62. hikey64_only-trunk_staging-userdebug
     63. hikey960-trunk_staging-userdebug
     64. hikey960_tv-trunk_staging-userdebug
     65. hikey_tv-trunk_staging-userdebug
     66. poplar-trunk_staging-eng
     67. poplar-trunk_staging-user
     68. poplar-trunk_staging-userdebug
     69. qemu_trusty_arm64-trunk_staging-userdebug
     70. rb5-trunk_staging-userdebug
     71. riscv64-trunk_staging-eng
     72. sdk_car_arm64-trunk_staging-userdebug
     73. sdk_car_md_x86_64-trunk_staging-userdebug
     74. sdk_car_portrait_x86_64-trunk_staging-userdebug
     75. sdk_car_x86_64-trunk_staging-userdebug
     76. silvermont-trunk_staging-eng
     77. uml-trunk_staging-userdebug
     78. yukawa-trunk_staging-userdebug
     79. yukawa_sei510-trunk_staging-userdebug
```

If I type in `lunch sdk_phone_x86_64-userdebug`, it will respond with `Invalid lunch combo: lunch sdk_phone_x86`. Did I miss out anything when i was cloning the repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem for myself by switching the repo branch.

Instead of just doing

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

Do

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-13.0.0_r78
```

You can adjust the android version to the version you need. (https://source.android.com/docs/setup/about/build-numbers#source-code-tags-and-builds)

now you can do

```
repo sync
```

After those steps the correct options showed up for me.