Missing 'sdk_phone_x86_64' from lunch options
When trying to lunch AOSP I dont have the option for 'sdk_phone_x86_64' (Needed for emulator)
Any help is appreciated.
I saw a similar thread where the repo sync address was changed, even following this advice my options are as follow (Still no sdk_phone)
Invalid lunch combo: lunch sdk_phone_x86

aosp_arm-eng
aosp_arm64-eng
aosp_barbet-userdebug
aosp_bluejay-userdebug
aosp_bluejay_car-userdebug
aosp_bramble-userdebug
aosp_bramble_car-userdebug
aosp_car_arm-userdebug
aosp_car_arm64-userdebug
aosp_car_x86-userdebug
aosp_car_x86_64-userdebug
aosp_cf_arm64_auto-userdebug
aosp_cf_arm64_phone-userdebug
aosp_cf_x86_64_foldable-userdebug
aosp_cf_x86_64_only_phone_hsum-userdebug
aosp_cf_x86_64_pc-userdebug
aosp_cf_x86_64_phone-userdebug
aosp_cf_x86_64_tv-userdebug
aosp_cf_x86_auto-userdebug
aosp_cf_x86_phone-userdebug
aosp_cf_x86_tv-userdebug
aosp_cheetah-userdebug
aosp_cloudripper-userdebug
aosp_coral-userdebug
aosp_coral_car-userdebug
aosp_felix-userdebug
aosp_flame-userdebug
aosp_flame_car-userdebug
aosp_lynx-userdebug
aosp_oriole-userdebug
aosp_oriole_car-userdebug
aosp_panther-userdebug
aosp_raven-userdebug
aosp_raven_car-userdebug
aosp_ravenclaw-userdebug
aosp_redfin-userdebug
aosp_redfin_car-userdebug
aosp_redfin_vf-userdebug
aosp_slider-userdebug
aosp_sunfish-userdebug
aosp_sunfish_car-userdebug
aosp_tangorpro-userdebug
aosp_trout_arm64-userdebug
aosp_trout_x86_64-userdebug
aosp_whitefin-userdebug
aosp_x86-eng
aosp_x86_64-eng
arm_krait-eng
arm_v7_v8-eng
armv8-eng
armv8_cortex_a55-eng
armv8_kryo385-eng
beagle_x15-userdebug
beagle_x15_auto-userdebug
car_ui_portrait-userdebug
car_x86_64-userdebug
db845c-userdebug
gsi_car_arm64-userdebug
gsi_car_x86_64-userdebug
hikey-userdebug
hikey64_only-userdebug
hikey960-userdebug
hikey960_tv-userdebug
hikey_tv-userdebug
poplar-eng
poplar-user
poplar-userdebug
qemu_trusty_arm64-userdebug
rb5-userdebug
sdk_car_arm-userdebug
sdk_car_arm64-userdebug
sdk_car_portrait_x86_64-userdebug
sdk_car_x86-userdebug
sdk_car_x86_64-userdebug
sdk_pc_x86_64-userdebug
silvermont-eng
uml-userdebug
yukawa-userdebug
yukawa_sei510-userdebug


Please refer this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77457351/invalid-lunch-combo-lunch-sdk-phone-x86

Which version of Android are you trying to build, Android 15?
It looks like they retired the sdk_phone target. They also added a release segment to lunch in Android 15 though I'm not yet clear on the meaning. It is mentioned at https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building now.
I believe that lunch aosp_x86_64-trunk_staging-userdebug should get you a working goldfish emulator in Android 15. Your target list didn't include the release segment so you might also try lunch aosp_x86_64-userdebug or possibly lunch sdk_pc_x86_64-userdebug.

Reply by Ivan Meler, on a different forum in case anyone requires answer here.
"Try manually launching it, that menu has sort of been deprecated few months ago"
Meaning the lunch option may not appear but you can still use the command
'lunch sdk_phone_x86_64' works and allows me to use the emulator. (You may still require changing the repo address as stated in original post).
